# Parsing JSONObject in Java to access its keys

Tags: java, parsing, json

I am new to java so sorry if my question is primitive, I have a json like :

and I want to iterate based on number of items in JSONObject:

```
public static void main(String[] args, int value)
{
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try {
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("/Users/.../Documents/workspace/changeReturn/bin/availableCash.json"));


            for (int n=0; n < ((String) obj).length(); n++)
            {
                ...
            }

        }

}
```

How can I get the value of obj element e.g. "2" for "$100" or "5" for "$50" and save it in **objValue** so that I can continue my operation listed in the code above.

Comment: Your problem is that you think the parser result is an Object, since the input JSON is an "object".  They are different things -- a JSON "object" is like a Java Map.  It's not clear which JSON kit you're using (there are several that have `JSONParser` or `JsonParser`) but what's returned from `parse` is usually something like a `JSONElement`.  You can then test its type and `getAsJsonObject` or some such to get the Map equivalent object.  Then, if the particular kit is a good one, you can get the list of keys and fetch the values.

Answer (score -1):

There is a library for this!

[JSON in Java](http://www.json.org/java/)

The library here allows us to take a JSON object, read it from an InputStream and access it.

You can download that library
[here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/archive/master.zip)

Hopefully this helps you out, I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do.

Example:

```
                JSONObject obj = new ("{\n" +
"    \"$100\":\"2\",\n" +
"    \"$50\":\"5\",\n" +
"    \"$30\":\"3\",\n" +
"    \"$10\":\"8\",\n" +
"    \"$5\":\"4\",\n" +
"}");
obj.get("$100"); //returns 2
```